# Using an Object Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following JavaScript and I would like to add the relevant days to a Date object and then save this. I am attempting this as follows

```
let orderIdDateCorrectionDict = [ 
    { "orderId": "2020053100", "dayCorrection": -146 }, 
    { "orderId": "2020053109", "dayCorrection": -146 }, 
    { "orderId": "2020053100", "dayCorrection": -146 }, 
];

migrateUp(db.Orders);
var index = 0;

function migrateUp(targetCollection) {

    targetCollection.find({
        OrderId: { $in: orderIdDateCorrectionDict.map(i => i.orderId) }
    }).forEach(
        function (order) {

            order.TransDate.DateTime = order.TransDate.DateTime.addDays(orderIdDateCorrectionDict[index++].dayCorrection);
            order.TransDate.Ticks = NumberLong((order.TransDate.DateTime.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);

            targetCollection.save(order);
        }
    );
};

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

It is giving me the error

{
    "message" : "Cannot read property 'dayCorrection' of undefined",
    "stack" : "script:9478:126" +
              "script:14:70" +
              "script:14:70" +
              "script:9475:8" +
              "script:9460:1"
}

How can I update the relevant record with the correct day int value?

Answer (score 0):

The error is evidence that there are duplicate order ids in the data. As a result, the find produces more orders than there are elements in `orderIdDateCorrectionDict`, and the `index` gets incremented beyond the end of that array, producing an undefined value (and thus "cannot read property ... of undefined")

As a debug step, confirm that you get *exactly* N orders when querying N ids. If you don't, then you have non-unique ids, and the fix should be made elsewhere, wherever those duplicates are created.

To guard the OP code against this problem, independent how the ids are setup, don't use a parallel `index` counter.  Instead, lookup the correction by orderId, like this...

```
function orderCorrectionForId(orderId) {
  return orderIdDateCorrectionDict.find(oc => oc.orderId === orderId)
}

// no need for the index variable
// in the forEach loop...

function (order) {
  let correction = orderCorrectionForId(order.OrderId)
  if (correction) {
    order.TransDate.DateTime = order.TransDate.DateTime.addDays(correction.dayCorrection);
    // and so on...
  }
```

But start with just logging the `order` in that `forEach` function, so you can get to the root problem, which is a query result that you don't expect.